# In single-spa, how do I prevent a utility module from unmounting on route change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, micro-frontend, single-spa

I am developing a micro frontend app using single spa and react. I have created a utility module for data sharing and have loaded it in the root url `/`. But each time I change the application URL, the utility module is getting reinitialized. Is there any way to prevent the utility module from getting unmounted so that I can persist data across applications?

Comment: If your goal is to share data between URLs, then why did you attach the module to an URL?

Comment: @GuerricP My goal is to share data between individual apps running inside the single-spa framework. In such a scenario, don't I have to attach that to any URL?

Comment: @LawrenceMoraira Not sure what exactly you mean by unmounting when you are referring utility module. Assuming your utility module would be a simple in-browser module that you would be loading with systemjs in the index file unless you are using some framework for the utility module as well.

Comment: I agree with @roanjain. There shouldn't be any reason to tie a utility module to a URL like single-spa applications do.

Comment: Got the solution. Thanks

Comment: And do you probably want to share your solution?

Comment: @dennis-de-laat I think the solution is to import utility module in root-config, and pass util module exports as custom props to applications, like so: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/single-spa-authentication-state-management-using-react-rolando-niub%C3%B3/